# Merge 2 DataFrame and sum up one of the column

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframes that I would like to merge in pandas (Python 2.7).

In the merge (DataFrame C) the same ID and Sub_id must be only one line and their Views must add up.

My DataFrame A

```
--------------------------------
ID | Sub_ID | Views 
--------------------------------
345 | 4 | 120 
555 | 8 | 133 
122 | 4 | 540
333 | 2 | 40
```

My DataFrame B

```
--------------------------------
ID | Sub_ID | Views 
--------------------------------
345 | 4 | 110 
555 | 8 | 100 
122 | 4 | 544
```

I would like to get a new Dataframe that will be the sum of the Views of both DataFrame A and B only if their ID and Sub_id match:

Result DataFrame C

```
--------------------------------
ID | Sub_ID | Views 
--------------------------------
345 | 4 | 230 
555 | 8 | 233 
122 | 4 | 1084
333 | 2 | 40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
df3.groupby(['ID', 'Sub_ID'], as_index=False).sum()
```

```py
    ID  Sub_ID  Views
0   122 4   1084
1   333 2   40
2   345 4   230
3   555 8   233
```